# Как вывести информацию из БД в Asp Net Core?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-core

Всем привет, возможно странный вопрос, но все таки, есть приложение на ASP Net Core 3.1, подключена БД MS SQL-Server, как можно сохранить несколько значений из одной таблицы для дальнейшего их использования в программе, например сохранить первые три значения первого столбца, второго столбца и третьего столбца, чтобы потом можно было вывести эти значения, например в JSON-файл

Пример БД 
Столбец1 | Столбец2 | Столбец3
Значение1| Значение1| Значение1
Значение2| Значение2| Значение2
Значение3| Значение3| Значение3

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под словом "сохранить"? Может, вы хотите их получить их БД? Укажите, какую технологию используете при работе с БД.

Comment: Под словом сохранить я имею ввиду сохранить в переменную или массив, внтури программы, чтобы потом была возможность обращаться к ним
Технология EF Core

Comment: Слишком широкий вопрос. Вам сначала надо прочитать учебник по работе с базами данных, иначе ответ тут будет на десятки страниц. Начните например с этого: https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/